# Is the following claim true? (about a function that is strictly increasing and surjective)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

We have a function $f$, $f:I \to F$, where $I$ is an open-ended interval, and $F$ is also an interval. $f$ is strictly increasing and surjective. I was trying to prove the fact that $f$ is continuous, which I have managed to do it by myself (I won't describe here how, because it's not relevant for the question). Also, let $L$ be its left-side limit.

I had the curiosity to read the proof gave by my textbook and it's pretty much the same as mine.

But they use the following fact: if $f$ is not continuous at a point $x_0$,then, then $\forall x, x < x_0$ we have $f(x) < L< f(x_0) $.

I agree that $ L < f(x_0) $ (it can be proven that this is true if $f$ is monotone, and I have done so) but I believe that the other part of the inequality is not true. Am I correct, or am I missing something? I asked this here because I wanted to be sure.

Comment: If I read the question correctly,you're just given $f\colon I\to F$, why should it be continuous or monotonic?

Comment: You say that $f$ is surjective. Do you also know that $F$ is an interval? If it isn't, then $f$ is not continuous. (I presume from the statement that $f$ is strictly increasing that $F\subset \mathbb R$.)

Comment: @Git Gud, I have edited my question. I forgot to specify that f is also surjective and strictly increasing.

Comment: @MPW, yes, F is an interval. Apparently I forgot to mention that also. So, what do you think about the other part of the inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left side limit means $\lim_{x\to x_0-} f(x)$=L. So for all $x<x_0 f(x)<L$ [Because f is monotonic]. If I have misunderstood your question please tell me, I will try to give the answer.

Comment: Indeed, that was my question. Hmm, I will give it a little tought because I don't understand why this inequality is true.

Comment: The answer was pretty obvious..it follows from the fact that L is the supremum of the set of al the values f(x), with x < x_0. And hence, that part of the inequality is also true..

Comment: Yup. Right you are.